My question "Why does one of the HR personnel is mad at me?" (2)
My 1st post got closed I don't know why, I am a newbie here. I hope those who commented on my post before could do it again here with their responds on my replies.
So I am an intern right now together with my 2 friends that are both female. The company and other employees are friendly except for this HR personnel. She's so mad at me. Take note: ONLY AT ME. I don't know why. For instance, other interns are late, she will just ask them why she/he is late and when they answered why, she'll just respond "oh, okay". But when I was late she said "You should wake up earlier", "Make some adjustment to your body clock or routine" and she asked me if I already undergo orientation because it's look like I am unaware that being late is not okay. But the reason why I am late because I am not feeling well and waited a few minutes if I can really go to work. And also I am aware that late is not okay that's why ahead of time, I already ask or chatted my supervisor (to whom I am reporting to) that I might be late or absent. Also, everytime someone from the office ask for my help to do this and that, she will watch me for her to find mistakes on what I am doing and later on she will be able to embarass me in front of the applicants and other employees inside the office. I don't know what to do. I am running for latin honor and I am scared that she might be the done who will answer the evaluation. Help me guys! What should I do?

This is a duplicated question. Here is your original question: Why is one of the HR personnel mad at me even though I didn't do anything wrong?

@Emely Welcome to Workplace SE, I appreciate that you're new to the site and are unfamiliar with the way SE sites work but please don't repost questions when they get closed as this will only result in the duplicates being closed. As it stands your original question has received an edit to try and make it more suitable for the site and been submitted for review by the community and has already got one re-open vote.
